# Next auth jwt signature

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, openid, next-auth

I am currently implementing OAuth login to my next.js website using a custom OAuth provider. I am using the next-auth library. This is my current configuration (pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts):

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    {
      id: "ow4",
      name: "Online Web 4 Authorization",
      type: "oauth",
      authorization: {
        params: { scope: "openid profile onlineweb4" },
      },
      clientSecret: process.env.OW_CLIENT_SECRET,
      clientId: process.env.OW_CLIENT_ID,
      wellKnown:
        "https://old.online.ntnu.no/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.id,
          name: profile.first_name + profile.last_name,
          email: profile.email,
        };
      },
    },
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

After I login on the OAuth client, I get redirected back to my webpage with this error in my terminal:

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error failed to validate JWT signature {
  error: RPError: failed to validate JWT signature
      at Client.validateJWT (C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\OnlineOpptak\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:1086:11)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async Client.validateIdToken (C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\OnlineOpptak\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:766:49)       
      at async Client.callback (C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\OnlineOpptak\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:505:7)
      at async oAuthCallback (C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\OnlineOpptak\node_modules\next-auth\core\lib\oauth\callback.js:109:16)       
      at async Object.callback (C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\OnlineOpptak\node_modules\next-auth\core\routes\callback.js:52:11)
      at async AuthHandler (C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\OnlineOpptak\node_modules\next-auth\core\index.js:208:28)
      at async NextAuthApiHandler (C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\OnlineOpptak\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:22:19)
      at async NextAuth._args$ (C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\OnlineOpptak\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:108:14)
      at async Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\OnlineOpptak\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:366:9) {   
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'ow4',
  message: 'failed to validate JWT signature'
}
```

After looking in the node module where the error was thrown it looks like the reason the error occours is because the OAuth provider's JWKS is not valid?:

```
for (const key of keys) {
  const verified = await jose
    .compactVerify(jwt, key instanceof Uint8Array ? key : await key.keyObject(header.alg))
    .catch(() => {});
  if (verified) {
    return {
      payload,
      protected: verified.protectedHeader,
      key,
    };
  }
}

throw new RPError({
  message: 'failed to validate JWT signature',
  jwt,
});
```

I don't have much experienced with OAuth, so I don't know what this means.

Has anyone encountered this issue before, or know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: If there are any keys in the `keys` array then JWKS is fine. You could try to debug your app in the point you showed to check what is in the keys array and what the jwt looks like. You can also check what is being done in the `compactVerify` method, whether it's just checking the signature or any content (e.g. if the token is expired).

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski, I did some more debugging and got this error:

`TypeError: RS256 requires key modulusLength to be 2048 bits or larger`

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with the public key. You should contact the OAuth provider and verify with them.